# cv error: "Call to undefined function Civi\Cv\Command\posix_getuid()"

Tags: cv

When I run `cv` on a server, I get the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]                                                                                                                                                         
Call to undefined function Civi\Cv\Command\posix_getuid()
```

Furthermore, I noticed that usually when I run `cv --help` the output is in color - on this server the output is in black and white.

Answer (score 5):

`cv` has a PHP dependency that CiviCRM doesn't - the `posix` plugin.  It's installed by default on many systems with PHP (e.g. Debian/Ubuntu) but with the Red Hat/CentOS "remi" repository, it isn't.  You can [install the php-process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40411083/no-colors-in-php-cli) package to resolve this.